# Flatten multiple nested hierarchial array - d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, flatten

I have an an array with four levels that I would like to have flattened.

Simplified code with two starting array-elements and flattening of the lowest level:

```
var tstArray = [{Count:2,Yr:2008,Dep:"NDep_1",Periodtype:"Week",Period:1,Beds:5},
                {Count:9,Yr:2008,Dep:"NDep_2",Periodtype:"Week",Period:1,Beds:10}
                ];
console.log(tstArray);

tstArray = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) { return d.Periodtype;})
                    .key(function(d) { return d.Yr;})
                    .key(function(d) { return d.Period;})
                    .key(function(d) { return d.Dep;})
                    .rollup(function(d) { 
                            return {"Count":d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.Count; }), "Beds":d3.sum(d, function(j) {return j.Beds;})};
                        }).entries(tstArray);

console.log(tstArray);

tstArray =  tstArray.map(function(d){
    var Periodtype = d.key
    var values1 = d.values.map(function(e){
        var Yr = e.key
        var values2 = e.values.map(function(f){
            var Period = f.key;
            var values3 = f.values.map(function(g){
                return{'Dep':g.key,Count':+g.values.Count,'Beds':+g.values.Beds}
            });
            return {'Period':Period,'values3':values3}
        });
        var tmparr = [];
        for (   var i = 0, len=values2.length; i < len; i++) {                                  
            for (   var j = 0, lenj=values2[i].values3.length; j < lenj; j++) {
                tmparr.push({    'Period':values2[i].Period,
                                 'Dep':values2[i].values3[j].Dep,
                                 'Count': +values2[i].values3[j].Count,
                                 'Beds': +values2[i].values3[j].Beds
                            });
             };  
         };

         return{'Year':Yar,'values2':tmparr}

      });
      return{'Periodtype':Periodtype,'values1':values1} })
                        ;

console.log(tstArray);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j28t8cLo/1/)

Now, I have one solution, I think. I could just redo this for the lowest level (three more goes) but that seems to be a bad way to go about this. How can i get all the flattening in one go? I have tried but I have had little luck with values3. I still understand these concepts too shallowly. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for recursion.  Take a look at the `flatten` function [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288).  (If you want to become completely comfortable with recursion, but are not already, I recommend the book *The Little Schemer*.)

Comment: if it's not a problem for you to use other libraries, you could use the .flatten function in underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/#flatten), which seems to not care about sub-levels

Comment: @Mars : Thanks, it does indeed flatten but can I flatten it to an array of arrays easy enough?

Comment: @tomtomtom: Thanks, I have seen quite a few useful functions from that library but if I try to avoid adding more libraries at this point.

Comment: I haven't thought through whether that *particular* function is what you need.  It's probably not.  I think it illustrates, in outline, a method that you can adapt to do what you want.  Your problem, as I understand it, is how to flatten multiple levels in a simple way.  The easiest way to do that is with recursion.  Bostock's `flatten` is just one of many illustrations that you could use as a starting point for writing your own `flatten` function.  once you fully understand the concepts, everything I'm saying will become obvious.

Comment: If you don't want to flatten the outer/top level, just loop over the outer array, applying a flatten function to each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some help on which routes to explore I settled for a for-loop, mainly because the arrays are fixed and it was the easiest to get my head around.

```
var tmparr = [];
for (   var i = 0, len=values2.length; i < len; i++) {                                  
    for (   var j = 0, lenj=values2[i].values3.length; j < lenj; j++) {
       tmparr.push({    'Period':values2[i].Period,
                        'Dep':values2[i].values3[j].Dep,
                        'Count': +values2[i].values3[j].Count,
                        'Beds': +values2[i].values3[j].Beds
                   });
    };  
};

return{'Year':Yar,'values2':tmparr}
```

I then repeated this loop on the next level (I did this mainly for readability, by doing it this way I didn't have to nest more than two levels of for-loops).